# Hint to my homework (measure and integration)

Tags: integration

The following is an excercise from a list of problems in measure and integration theory.

The problem as it was state in class reads as follows:

> Let $v$ be a measure in [0,1]. Show that
>   $$\int_{[0,1]}t\cdot v(\mathrm{d}t)=\int_{0}^{1}v([s,1])\,\mathrm{d}s$$

As my teacher said, some problems are stated imprecisely or with missing details. In the above problem, for example, no $\sigma$-algebra in $[0,1]$ is specified.  Based on the course notes, the LHS is meant to be the Lebesgue integral of $t$ in the interval $[0,1]$ with respect to the measure $v$.

What most confuses me is the RHS.

Comment: In the RHS we integrate something that seems to not depend on $s$, so the result should be this constant. Now we only need to know what is $v$, what kind of object, and what is by convention $v(dt)$. Usually such questions get many downvotes, so please add needed details and the own thoughts in the direction of a solution to avoid in time a frustrating situation for all sides.

Comment: Assuming that $v$ is a measure, what you're asking is false. Probably you simply didn't copy the problem correctly...

Comment: The problem as I stated in the first try was indeed wrong, @DavidC.Ullrich. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I appreciate your comments,@dan_fulea. I hope the changes I made have turned the question more clear.